# Iterating over ArrayList items with JSTL forEach

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm having problem running over ArrayList items and displaying them in JSP file.

Here is my bean:

```
public class UsersList {
    private ArrayList<UserDetails> users = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();

    public ArrayList getUsers(  ){
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<UserDetails> users){
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

users contains UserDetails which is simply class with 3 String properties: email, username, password

Now I am trying to display the details in a table.. first in index.jsp I have those commands:

```
            UsersList bean = new UsersList();
            bean.setUsers(db.getUsersList()); // getting all user deatils from database into the list
            session.setAttribute("bean", bean);

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/adminPage.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

And now on adminPage.jsp when I should display the table containing the users details, its displays nothing. Here is the code:

```
<c:forEach var="current" items="${bean.users}" >
<tr>
    <td>${current.email}</td>
    <td>${current.username}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="${current.email}"</td>
</tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Any idea what's the problem here?? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any error.. I'm using NetBeans but I have no idea how to debug core tag things like forEach .. No error occures, the table is empty instead of contains the details

Comment: Maybe its happening because im missing the web-xml file???

Comment: Did you define the taglib on your JSP? `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Comment: In future JSP/HTML related problems, please always rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to verify if the generated HTML output is all right. You should have seen `<c:forEach>` tags still in the HTML output which thus indicates that JSTL hasn't run at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your prefix "c" points to the right tag library.

It should be

> "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

If that does not work, check if there is mistake in the logic of populating the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since your adding the object to session you need to access it from sessionScope in EL.

```
<c:forEach var="current" items="${sessionScope.bean.users}" >
<tr>
    <td>${current.email}</td>
    <td>${current.username}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="${current.email}"</td>
</tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Are you sure the userdetails list contains details? Set a breakpoint in debug to check the list.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked.. It contains the details. Maybe its something with the declaration of: UsersList bean = new UsersList();
in the try scope in index.jsp file??

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but try ${session.bean.users} for the items attribute.  I need to make an appointment, I will check your progress when I return later.  Also you can setbreakpoints in jsp, which might be worth a try.

Comment: still nada.. but thanks for helping me. Hope I will solve that until then

Comment: The `${sessionScope}` map access is only necessary when you have an attribute with the same name `bean` in page and/or request scope as well (which is in turn actually bad design). This does not seem to be the case at all. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info